# Can i use TrackBy to track a particular state in Corda Vault?

Tags: corda

https://docs.corda.net/api-vault-query.html specifies that  *"TrackBy updates do not take into account the full criteria specification due to different and more restrictive syntax in observables filtering (vs full SQL-92 JDBC filtering as used in snapshot views). Specifically, dynamic updates are filtered by contractStateType and stateType (UNCONSUMED, CONSUMED, ALL) only"* (edited)

Does that mean that i cannot track a particular record ( state) in my vault based on its properties other than stateType? (edited)

This is what i have noticed also. I used a LinearStateQueryCriteria based on externalID but instead of updates of that one record, i got updates for all the records of the particular contractStateType.

Looking for confirmation so i can try another strategy.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you could use `trackBy` to monitor the state type you need and in the observable filter to only include states with the `externalId` that you desire. This might not be ideal but will achieve the goal you are looking for.

Comment: Dan is correct, this is the best approach as of Corda 3.3. You would have to do your own observable filtering (see http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html and https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Filtering-Observables).